# How can I make my desktop quieter?

Tags: audio, desktop-computer

My computer is very loud, how do you recommend I make it quieter?

What steps can I take to make it sound softer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install silicon washers on disk drive and fan mounts, to dampen vibration.  Replace components with quieter ones.  Underclock your PC.  Clean your PC (as SS said).  Move the PC farther away.  Get sound dampening cushions and install then between line-of-site(sound) between you and the PC (make sure it does not block airflow).

Answer (score 0):

Your computer being loud is generally the fans hard at work keeping your computer from exploding. Here's a few possibilities to make it quieter:

- Get some compressed air, and clean out the dust. More dust can slow down the fans, and in turn make it louder.
- Get new fans. These things get old you know!
- Water cooling. Still uses fans, but isn't nearly as loud.

Comment: The bigger fans the better. Slightly counter-intuitive, as big things are normally louder, but a bigger fan moves more air with each spin, so has to spin less! *Science!*

Comment: Also see: [Suck or blow? What's better for dust?](http://superuser.com/questions/270751/suck-or-blow-whats-better-for-dust)