# Will using a bicycle pump to clean my laptop damage it?

Tags: laptop, fan, cleaning, maintenance

I have a Lenovo G580 laptop. Unfortunately, there is no way to access the fan even after opening maintenance hatch, so I have no real way of removing dust from the cooling vents without using some form of compressed air. I can't afford or procure canned compressed air anyway.

Therefore, I've used a bicycle pump with a needle (the kind used to fill basketballs) to pump air through the fan vents. It seems to work well and I can see a lot of dust come the out vents when I pump air through it. But I'm concerned that using it could lead to static buildup on the component parts. Could this damage components of the laptop?

The pump-needle setup looks like this:

[image]

Comment: [This answer](http://superuser.com/a/605577/55325) would imply that it is not dangerous, since the static buildup on a vacuum nozzle comes from charged dust particles. I don't know whether this is accurate. In any event, keeping the needle away from sensitive components should help.

Comment: Yes it could be a problem. Having metal that close to components could allow a spark to jump....